# How does HTTP specify the end of a response for Transfer-encoding: chunked?

Tags: http

From this [wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Server_response)
 a typical HTTP response may look like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Length: 138
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close

<html>
<head>
  <title>An Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.
</body>
</html>
```

In this case because of this header:

```
Connection: close
```

the client will know that the HTTP body has finished, because the TCP connection will be closed, Say for example `Connection: close` wasn't present, the client would still know the HTTP body was finished because  this header:

```
Content-Length: 138
```

Is saying, once you get 138 bytes, we're done here. But in the case where neither of these headers are used and instead the server sends `Transfer-encoding: chunked` how does a browser know when a response has completed, so that it can move onto other things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding):

> The **chunked** keyword in the **Transfer-Encoding** header is used to
>   indicate chunked transfer. Each chunk is preceded by its size. **The
>   transmission ends when a zero-length chunk is encountered.**

Comment: wow, you nailed it :) If I could I would accept this (Stackoverflow imposed time limit)